# Adding pipeline demands at run time in ADO YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

How do I write my ADO YAML in such a way that there might be demands such as Agent.Name = 'abc' that might be needed occasionally while queuing the build?
An example is if we want to investigate a build failure that is happening on a specific build agent
Another use case is if there is a software upgrade such as .NET core and we want to test our build on the upgraded software on one agent before we upgrade the software on all the build agents

Classic pipelines had the ability to add demands without updating the pipeline.

[image]

Comment: I do not think it is possible but try to come with example of what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Why would you want to do it? Agents should be disposable. Or in rare cases, they should be pre-configured with custom applications. It looks like you are trying to use Azure DevOps for task scheduling (run a task on a specific arbitrary machine), if it's true, Azure DevOps is not meant for it.

Comment: Have you tried to use parameters?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters

Comment: @MaythamFahmi, Thank you for your help! I updated my original question with a use case.

Comment: @VladDX A use case is when a build is failing on a specific agent and we want to investigate and re-test or if there is a software upgrade such as .NET core and we want to test our build on the upgraded software on one agent before we upgrade the software on all the agents

Comment: You can define a user-defined capability only for one agent. Then just use this in `demand`. Agents docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents
Demands docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands

Comment: @VladDX sorry for not being clear, but I dont want to edit the YAML file. Classic pipelines had the ability where we could define the demands without updating the pipeline. I edited the original question with the screenshot. Wondering if there is a way to achieve that in YAML pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a YAML Pipeline in Azure DevOps and use parameter to tweak the demands:

```yaml
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

parameters:
# Define a parameter
- name: demand
  displayName: Demand
  type: string
  default: DefaultPool
  values:
  - DefaultPool
  - SpecialSoftware

variables:
  demand: '${{ parameters.demand }}'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  # Use the variable
  ${{ if ne(variables['demand'], '') }}:
    demands: ${{variables.demand}}

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

When you want to manually run the pipeline, you can choose the value for the `demand` parameter:

[image: Azure Pipeline with parameter]

---

**Documentation**:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents

Comment: I tried that before I reached out to this forum. I was getting "A template expression is not allowed in this context" for this line of code demands: ${{ parameters.demand }}

Comment: It would be good if you would mention what you have tried and what doesn't work in your original question. I updated my answer, please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ADO cannot read parameters in the same "stage" they are defined. So to get around that I ended up creating jobs and reading the parameter there. In this case it would look something like this:

```yaml
parameters:
# Define a parameter
- name: demand
  displayName: Demand
  type: string
  default: DefaultPool
  values:
  - DefaultPool
  - SpecialSoftware

jobs:
  - job: My pipeline job
    pool:
      name: My_Pool
      demands: ${{ parameters.demand }}
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```